# Is displayName a replacement for username in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In Firebase I can define a displayName for a user. Is this a alternative for a username, or something else? Can I force unique displayNames, or must I store it in a seperate document with security rules?

Answer (score 0):

A display name is just what the user would want others to see when, for example, viewing their profile.  It's not unique.  You're not obliged to use it in any way.